# How to get Kendo-UI grid row data when text values changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using Kendo UI for jQuery. My grid has 2 columns: a floating-point number and text. I need to get a grid row when values change. For a numeric field, everything works fine, but for a text field, it doesn't: the handler function is called, but how do I get the grid data in it? (I use the same handler, but it doesn't matter).

```
export class MyGrid {
    constructor() {
        let that: MyGrid = this;

        $("#MyGrid").kendoGrid({
            dataBound: function (e) {
                this.tbody.find(".MyNumericValue").each(function () {
                    $(this).kendoNumericTextBox({
                        format: "n3",
                        decimals: 3,
                        change: that.onValueChange.bind(that)
                    });
                });

                // Event function is called, but how to get row data?
                this.tbody.find(".MyTextValue").each(function () {
                    $(this).on("change", that.onValueChange.bind(that))
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Columns:

```
let columns = [
    {
        title: "Decimal value",
        field: "RoadLength",
        template: "<input name='RoadLength' class='MyNumericValue' value='#: RoadLength #' />"
    },
    {
        title: "Text value",
        field: "Name",
        template: "<input name='Name' class='k-textbox MyTextValue' value='#: Name #' />"
    }
];
```

Event: for textbox "*e.sender.element.closest("tr")*" does not work.

```
onValueChange(e: any): void {
    let g = $("#MyGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    let dataItem = g.dataItem(e.sender.element.closest("tr"));
    let name: string = e.sender.element[0].name;
    let value = e.sender.value();
    // dataItem.set(name, value);    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With kendoNumericTextBox's change event, e.sender is the kendoNumericTextBox itself, and *[e.sender.element](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/widget/fields/element)* is the jQuery instance of the original widget. The above event handler should work well.

With normal text field, change event is a jQuery [event](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). There is no **e.sender** and therefore the code above will create an error.  In this case, we use $(e.target).

Your code should probably separate these two cases.

And by the way, an javascript error notifier extension for web browser like [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/javascript-errors-notifie/jafmfknfnkoekkdocjiaipcnmkklaajd) will help you easily identify the problem.

Hope this help!